# Install node CLI tool written in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface

I have followed jeroenouw [guide](https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/how-to-create-your-own-typescript-cli-with-node-js-1faf7095ef89) and build a node CLI script which looks like the one [here](https://github.com/lony/ts-cli-starter). I'm even able to run it locally by running the following commands:

- npm install
- npm run build
- node ./lib/src/index.js

Now I want this CLI to be installed globally and do not know how? I tried npm pack but did not find any solution with it.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the package folder:

```
npm link
```

Comment: If I run `npm run build && npm link` I get this error `89 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-cli-starter/lib/src/index.ts'`

Comment: This [commit](https://github.com/lony/ts-cli-starter/commit/2f36ad7f541a34aca98a598c7a5cd0937e3f4aa2) fixed it. You were right it was just missing the right bin path.